# bxslider show more than 1 image on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, bxslider

I am using [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/) on this site and I am trying to edit the number of images to be shown on the slider on mobile ([site here](http://rockefellerdentalgroup.com/)), from 1 to 3 (from 768px to 320px). I think I am looking in the right place, but I'm not sure how to change the # of slides shown.

HTML

```
<ul class="patient-slider">
   <?php
   $patients = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ub_pmeta_1', true);
   foreach($patients as $patient){
   ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $patient['p_url']; ?>">
      <div class="thumbnail2">
        <p><img src="<?php echo $patient['p_image']; ?>" /></p>
        <div class="overlay">
          <h3><?php echo $patient['p_name']; ?></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      </a></li>
    <?php } ?>  
  </ul>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery('.patient-slider').bxSlider({minSlides: 6,maxSlides: maxSlides ,moveSlides:1,slideWidth: 335,slideMargin: 1,pager : false });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set `minSlides` to 3 and `maxSlides` to 6 in the bxSlider settings. That will ensure there are always 3 slides shown no matter the screen size and up 6 shown on larger screen sizes. There is some interplay with `slideWidth` setting. That should probably be called `slideMAXWidth` as it governs the max width for a slide, not its actual width. The actual width will be calculated based on the screen size and `minSlides`.

Comment: thank you, there was actually some settings  above that set the min/max slides so I was able to change it that way. Another question, more CSS related - on mobile the slider has some right padding on it and for the life of my I can't remove it; you'll see on mobile the whole home page has that padding so you can see whitespace on the right side of the screen. I've hidden the slider and it fixes it, do you know how I can remove that padding completely when the slider is present?

Comment: @vytfla Not sure. I'd close this one out and open a new question.